# My network interface changes names, so DHCP / dhclient cannot operate on it

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, ethernet, dhclient

On some ArchLinux servers I've switched from `dhcpcd` to `dhclient`, but the servers are not receiving IP. Upon inspection with `journalctl` I see that, on all occasions the IP was not received, `dhclient` attempted to operate on the interface and **then** the interface got renamed. The lines in question are:

```
dhclient[461]: Failed to get interface index: No such device
...
kernel: igc 0000:6f:00.0 enp111s0: renamed from eth1
```

What is this "interface renaming" business and how is it possible that `dhclient` is not predictably ordered around it?

Then of course, later on, the following command fixes DHCP:

```
sudo systemctl restart dhclient@enp111s0.service
```

More logs:

```
May 14 19:03:32 serverski systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[487]: Cannot find device "enp111s0"
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: Failed to get interface index: No such device
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: Failed to get interface index: No such device
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: exiting.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: 
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: 
May 14 19:03:32 serverski dhclient[461]: exiting.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski systemd-udevd[380]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski systemd[1]: dhclient@enp111s0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 14 19:03:32 serverski systemd[1]: dhclient@enp111s0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=dhclient@enp111s0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=fail>
May 14 19:03:32 serverski systemd-udevd[427]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v247'.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski systemd-udevd[427]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski kernel: r8169 0000:70:00.1 enp112s0f1: renamed from eth0
May 14 19:03:32 serverski kernel: iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
May 14 19:03:32 serverski systemd-udevd[382]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v247'.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski systemd-udevd[382]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 14 19:03:32 serverski kernel: ee1004 0-0051: 512 byte EE1004-compliant SPD EEPROM, read-only
May 14 19:03:32 serverski kernel: ee1004 0-0053: 512 byte EE1004-compliant SPD EEPROM, read-only
May 14 19:03:32 serverski kernel: igc 0000:6f:00.0 enp111s0: renamed from eth1
```

Comment: About defining interface names: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration#Change_interface_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting a workaround to my own issue.

After troubles with `dhclient` (this question) as well as other troubles with `dhcpcd` (that I didn't fully get to the bottom of, but simply switching to `dhclient` as a drop-in replacement solved them, since for both you need to just to `systemctl enable dhclient@iface.service`), I have come to the conclusion it's best and cleanest, to ditch both `dhclient` and `dhcpcd` in favour of `systemd-networkd`, which can be configured easily to handle DHCP, see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-networkd#Wired_adapter_using_DHCP), without the need for extra packages.

Using `systemd-networkd`'s own DHCP handling logically would solve the naming issue since I believe it's the same systemd component that does the interface renaming.